# Phonegap not building to android

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using `Ubuntu 16.04 x64` to build my `Phonegap` project, I have installed `Android Studio` and `SDK`, updated all in the `SDK Manager`.

But when I try build with command `phonegap build android`, return fallowing error:

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.069 secs

phonegap build android --debug
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build android --debug ' ...
cp: no such file or directory: /home/lxuancheng/Documents/Projects/dont-press/www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png


cp: no such file or directory: /home/lxuancheng/Documents/Projects/dont-press/www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png


cp: no such file or directory: /home/lxuancheng/Documents/Projects/dont-press/www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png


cp: no such file or directory: /home/lxuancheng/Documents/Projects/dont-press/www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png


cp: no such file or directory: /home/lxuancheng/Documents/Projects/dont-press/www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png


cp: no such file or directory: /home/lxuancheng/Documents/Projects/dont-press/www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png


cp: no such file or directory: /home/lxuancheng/Documents/Projects/dont-press/www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png


cp: no such file or directory: /home/lxuancheng/Documents/Projects/dont-press/www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png


cp: no such file or directory: /home/lxuancheng/Documents/Projects/dont-press/www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png


cp: no such file or directory: /home/lxuancheng/Documents/Projects/dont-press/www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png


cp: no such file or directory: /home/lxuancheng/Documents/Projects/dont-press/www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png


cp: no such file or directory: /home/lxuancheng/Documents/Projects/dont-press/www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png


cp: no such file or directory: /home/lxuancheng/Documents/Projects/dont-press/www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png


cp: no such file or directory: /home/lxuancheng/Documents/Projects/dont-press/www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png


cp: no such file or directory: /home/lxuancheng/Documents/Projects/dont-press/www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png


cp: no such file or directory: /home/lxuancheng/Documents/Projects/dont-press/www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png


cp: no such file or directory: /home/lxuancheng/Documents/Projects/dont-press/www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png


cp: no such file or directory: /home/lxuancheng/Documents/Projects/dont-press/www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png


ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk-linux

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

:preBuild UP-TO-DATE

:preDebugBuild

UP-TO-DATE


:checkDebugManifest


:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileLint


:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest

:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript

UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues

UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources

UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl

UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets

UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest

UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:processDebugResources

UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources

UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug

UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug

UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders

UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug

UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:bundleDebug

UP-TO-DATE

:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary

UP-TO-DATE

:prepareDebugDependencies


:compileDebugAidl
 UP-TO-DATE

:compileDebugRenderscript
 UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig
 UP-TO-DATE

:generateDebugAssets
 UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets

UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues

UP-TO-DATE

:generateDebugResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:mergeDebugResources

UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources
/home/lxuancheng/Documents/Projects/dont-press/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values/values.xml:4 : AAPT: Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in Don't Press!)


 FAILED



FAILURE: 
Build failed with an exception.




* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.

> 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/24.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1



* Try:

Run with 
--stacktrace
 option to get the stack trace. Run with 
--info
 or 
--debug
 option to get more log output.



BUILD FAILED




Total time: 2.408 secs

Error: Error code 1 for command: /home/lxuancheng/Documents/Projects/dont-press/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/lxuancheng/Documents/Projects/dont-press/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Comment: Did you get some more meaningful error messages? The one you have posted just says the build did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

values.xml line 4 :

`AAPT: Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in Don't Press!)`

Please update your string to `Don\'t Press!` to escape the apostrophe.

Comment: Welcome. Just took a few seconds to scan the error output. Gradle is very verbose, if you know what to look for

Answer (score 0):

When you open up your project in Android Studio, it uses its own version of gradle and this version differs with the version that phonegap build uses most of the time.

Try this, it should work :

1. Delete android build files : `phonegap clean`
2. And then : `phonegap build android`

Answer (score 0):

I has create `Phonegap` project in another computer.

I resolved this problem re-created `Phonegap` project in my actual pc, and merged `www`folder.

And I have REPLACED `www` folder with my project, so it has not `www/res` folder, this maybe turn my project no build.